# Не сохраняются данные в FSM Aiogram

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу телеграм бот на aiogram.
Eсть FSM которая записывает 2 состояния.
Есть колбек хэндлер, в котором нужно реализовать проверку состояний которые записал выше FSM.
Как это можно реализовать?
Вот здесь загрузил часть кода с этими FSM и нужным колбэком.
Почему-то он не понимает, что находится в `data` после записи в FSM

```
class Form(StatesGroup):
    firstname = State() 
    lastname = State()
    reg_state_open = State()
    reg_state_closed = State()
 
# Close reg now button
    
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains = 'close_now')
async def close_now(message: types.CallbackQuery):
    if message.data == 'close_now':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.message.chat.id, text='Введите 1, чтобы закрыть дальнейшую регистрацию.')
        await Form.reg_state_closed.set() # Далее вводим 1 
        await message.answer()
 
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.reg_state_closed)
async def reg_state_open(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data1:
        data1['reg_state1'] = int(message.text) # сохраняю состояние 1 в data1['reg_state1']
        await message.answer(text='Регистрация успешно отключена 1')  
        print('1:', data1['reg_state1'])
        await state.finish()
 
 
# Open reg now button
 
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains = 'open_now')
async def close_now(message: types.CallbackQuery):
    if message.data == 'open_now':
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.message.chat.id, text='Введите 0, чтобы открыть дальнейшую регистрацию.')
        await State.set(Form.reg_state_open) # Далее вводим 0 
        await message.answer()
 
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.reg_state_open)
async def reg_state_closed(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data2:
        data2['reg_state2'] = int(message.text) # сохраняю состояние 0 в data2['reg_state2]
        await message.answer(text='Регистрация включена 0')
        print('0:', data2['reg_state2'])
        await state.finish()
 
# как в этом колбекхэндлере проверить записанные выше два состояния (1 и 0). Например, если выше я ввел 0 - выполняется проверка 0 ли в data2['reg_state2], если 0 то дальше можно выполнить регистрацию, если же проверка говорит, что там 1 - регистрация недоступна и этот хэндлер выдает сообщение об этом: 
 
# 'Online registration' button from /start menu
 
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains = 'reg')
async def donate (message: types.CallbackQuery):
    if data1['reg_state1'] == 0:
        if not db.exists_list(message.message.chat.id): # проверка существования пользователя в БД с помощью функции db.exists_list
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.message.chat.id, text='Для регистрации введите своё имя.')
            await State.set(Form.firstname) # далее вводим имя
            await message.answer(text='')
        else: # если пользователь существует в БД, то выводим:
            await message.answer('Вы уже зарегистрированы')
    else: # data2['reg_state2'] == 1 ? (если рега off то выдаем сообщение:)
        await message.answer('Регистрация уже отключена.')
        await message.answer()
```

Comment: Так вы же сразу после записи переменной в стейт делайте `state.finish()` что стирает все данные в стейте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам просто нужно сделать некоторые данные не стираемыми всякими `finish`, `reset_state`.
Вот так примерно. Код не проверял. По идее должно работать.

```
import typing

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

import config


# теперь все переменные в дате которые начинаются с _ будут нестираемыми
class GMemoryStorage(MemoryStorage):
    async def reset_state(self, *,
                          chat: typing.Union[str, int, None] = None,
                          user: typing.Union[str, int, None] = None,
                          with_data: typing.Optional[bool] = True):
        await self.set_state(chat=chat, user=user, state=None)
        if with_data:
            new_data = {}
            old_data = await self.get_data(chat=chat, user=user)
            for key, value in old_data.items():
                if key.startswith("_"):
                    new_data[key] = value

            await self.set_data(chat=chat, user=user, data=new_data)
        self._cleanup(chat, user)


bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = GMemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Form(StatesGroup):
    firstname = State()
    lastname = State()
    reg_state_open = State()
    reg_state_closed = State()


# Close reg now button
# почему именно text_contains? У вас же вроде точное сравнение должно быть
# @dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains='close_now')
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='close_now')
async def close_now(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    # называйте переменные адекватно, колбек - callback_query/callback/call, сообщение - message/msg
    # в идеале делать такой ансвер в начале колбека, чтобы он наверняка сработал
    await call.answer()
    # зачем второй раз проверка?
    # if call.data == 'close_now':
    # нет смысла усложнять себе жизнь юзая bot.send_message если
    # вы отправляете сообщение в этот же чат
    # await bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text='Введите 1, чтобы закрыть дальнейшую регистрацию.')
    await call.message.answer('Введите 1, чтобы закрыть дальнейшую регистрацию.')
    await Form.reg_state_closed.set()  # Далее вводим 1


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.reg_state_closed)
async def reg_state_open(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # hint: рекомендую сделать проверку, написал ли юзер число
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        # добавляем _ перед перменной
        # вместо int(message.text) делаем просто True
        data['_reg_off'] = True

    await message.answer('Регистрация успешно отключена 1')
    # смысл его сохранять если вы тут же делате finish?
    # UPD. теперь смысл есть
    await state.finish()


# Open reg now button
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='open_now')
async def close_now(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    # то же  самое
    # if message.data == 'open_now':
    # await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.message.chat.id, text='Введите 0, чтобы открыть дальнейшую регистрацию.')
    await call.message.answer('Введите 0, чтобы открыть дальнейшую регистрацию.')
    await State.set(Form.reg_state_open)  # Далее вводим 0


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.reg_state_open)
async def reg_state_closed(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        # если регистрацию не отключали то просто удалим данные из даты
        del data['_reg_off']
        await message.answer('Регистрация включена')
        await state.finish()


# 'Online registration' button from /start menu
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='reg')
async def donate(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await call.answer()

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        # если True то регистрация отключена
        if data.get('_reg_off') is True:
            await call.answer('Регистрация уже отключена.')
        # иначе включена
        else:
            # проверка существования пользователя в БД с помощью функции db.exists_list
            if not db.exists_list(call.message.chat.id):
                await call.message.answer('Для регистрации введите своё имя.')
                # await bot.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text='Для регистрации введите своё имя.')
                await State.set(Form.firstname)  # далее вводим имя
            else:  # если пользователь существует в БД, то выводим:
                await call.answer('Вы уже зарегистрированы')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: большое спасибо за столь детальный разбор, все работает!